# React native android app crash on storage(read,write) permission revoke at runtime manually from settings

Tags: java, android, react-native, crash, android-permissions

I am using react-native to develop an android app,the problem is if user gives storage permission the app works fine, but if after giving permission if user revoke storage(read, write) permission manually from settings, it causes app to crash. I have tried many things but none of them is working. It is a critical error which cant be handled from react-native side, it has to be handled from native android side.

I want to handle this behaviour because it will not be good for user experience. I have tried many things but none of them are working.

Thanks in advance for helping me and giving your precious time.

Comment: You can add your existing code to your question so that it will be more detailed.